# Usage of Dot / Period in R Functions

Tags: r

I recently saw a function in R where someone had used `.` as an argument. I can't seem to find any documentation on this (other than the use of ellipsis or "dot-dot-dot"). Can someone either point me in the direction of documentation or provide an example of usage?

```
hello.world <- function(.) "Hello World"
# function(.) is what I'm asking about.
```

Comment: this came up on cross validated as well, some other good tidbits over there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dot-in-r/10739#10739

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dot is a a valid character in symbol names just like any letter, so `.` is no different than let's say `a` - it has no special meaning in this context. You can write things like:

```
> . <- 10
> . + .
[1] 20
```

It may look strange but is valid in R. The above use `function(.)` is let's say unusual, but syntactically valid. Since the author did not reference `.` in the function body, we will never know if he meant `...` or just used it because he could.

Comment: It does have a slightly special meaning at the start of identifiers: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Identifiers

Comment: Not really. There are several conventions in R that make use of dots (hiding symbols, S3 dispatch, ...), but `.` as asked above has no special meaning.

Comment: it has a special meaning for `proto`: ["formal argument lists of methods must always have a first argument of dot (i.e. .) which signifies the object on which the method is operating. The dot refers to the current object in the same way that a dot refers to the current directory in UNIX"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/vignettes/proto.pdf)

Comment: @baptiste It is really just a convention that the author of `proto` prefers, you can in fact use any other name with no difference.

Comment: There is also some mention of it in the See Also section of `?"function"` with respect to return(.) but the sentence doesn't make much sense to me: `debug for debugging; using invisible inside return(.) for returning invisibly`

Comment: @SimonUrbanek indeed, you're right. I was misled by that statement in the vignette.

Comment: `.` also has several special meanings in formulas
("all the other variables", "the previous left-hand side", 
"the previous right-hand side": 
see `?as.formula` and `?update.formula`)
and it is a function in the `plyr` package.

Comment: @baptiste,  Thanks for pointing out that quote regarding dot and proto.  In fact, the quote is wrong or at least misleading and a FAQ related to it has now been added to the proto home page: http://code.google.com/p/r-proto/#FAQ

Answer (score 3):

While the answer given by Simon Urbanek is correct here's a reason the `.` is preferred over other characters as a function argument. In some situations, like `lapply` a function needs to receive an argument by design. But if there is no need of the argument inside the function we still need a dummy argument name.   A `.` is the smallest character - almost invisible, so you are not distracted by what the function is delivering. The `function(.)` is as good as `function()` but has an advantage that it will not give an error when used in `apply` family.

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation is frequently used in the *map* family for outer parameters. For instance, in `map()` function of the `purrr` package the `.x` parameter is a list or vector, and the `.f` parameter is a function of formula:

```
map(.x, .f, ...)
```

If we have a list `dat_list` we cannot make a reference to the `dat_list` inside the formula, as `dat_list` is not in the formula environment:

```
library(purrr)
map(dat_list, ~lm(var1 ~ var2, data = dat_list) )
Error in eval(predvars, data, env)
```

But we can reference the outer parameter inside the formula as `.x`:

```
map(dat_list, ~lm(var1 ~ var2, data = .x) )
```