# How to indicate factors in ggplot with horizontal line and Text

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this example:

```
    dataExample<-data.frame(Time=seq(1:10),
        Data1=runif(10,5.3,7.5),
        Data2=runif(10,4.3,6.5),
        Application=c("Substance1","Substance1","Substance1",
        "Substance1","Substance2","Substance2","Substance2",
        "Substance2","Substance1","Substance1"))
        dataExample

           Time    Data1    Data2 Application
        1     1 6.511573 5.385265  Substance1
        2     2 5.870173 4.512775  Substance1
        3     3 6.822132 5.109790  Substance1
        4     4 5.940528 6.281412  Substance1
        5     5 7.269394 4.680380  Substance2
        6     6 6.122454 6.015899  Substance2
        7     7 5.660429 6.113362  Substance2
        8     8 6.649749 4.344978  Substance2
        9     9 7.252656 4.764667  Substance1
        10   10 7.204440 5.835590  Substance1
```

I would like to indicate at which time any Substance was applied that is different from `dataExample$Application[1]`.

Here I show you the way I get this ploted, but I assume that there is a much easier way to do it with ggplot.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot)

plotDataExample<-function(DataFrame){
  longDF<-melt(DataFrame,id.vars=c("Time","Application"))
  p=ggplot(longDF,aes(Time,value,color=variable))+geom_line()

  maxValue=max(longDF$value)
  minValue=min(longDF$value)

  yAppLine=maxValue+((maxValue-minValue)/20)
  xAppLine1=min(longDF$Time[which(longDF$Application!=longDF$Application[1])])
  xAppLine2=max(longDF$Time[which(longDF$Application!=longDF$Application[1])])
  lineData=data.frame(x=c(xAppLine1,xAppLine2),y=c(yAppLine,yAppLine))

  xAppText=xAppLine1+(xAppLine2-xAppLine1)/2
  yAppText=yAppLine+((maxValue-minValue)/20)
  appText=longDF$Application[which(longDF$Application!=longDF$Application[1])[1]]
  textData=data.frame(x=xAppText,y=yAppText,appText=appText)

  p=p+geom_line(data=lineData,aes(x=x, y=y),color="black")
  p=p+geom_text(data=textData,aes(x=x,y=y,label = appText),color="black")
  return(p)
}
plotDataExample(dataExample)
```

[image]

**Question:**
Do you know a better way to get a similar result so that I could possibly indicate more than one factor (e.g. Substance3, Substance4 ...).

Comment: Surely you mean Substance3, Substance4...? Care to include more substances in your example?

Comment: In your data is there possibility that Substance1 and Substance2 changes more than once?

Comment: `dataExample<-data.frame(Time=seq(1:10),
        Data1=runif(10,5.3,7.5),
        Data2=runif(10,4.3,6.5),
        Application=c("Substance1","Substance2","Substance2",
        "Substance1","Substance1","Substance2","Substance2",
        "Substance2","Substance1","Substance1"))`

Comment: yes, it should change more than ones but my examle does not work this way. I would like to see more than one line if it changes more than ones.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik to add more substances:`dataExample<-data.frame(Time=seq(1:21),
        Data1=runif(21,5.3,7.5),
        Data2=runif(21,4.3,6.5),
        Application=c("Substance1","Substance1","Substance1",
        "Substance2","Substance2","Substance2",
  "Substance1","Substance1","Substance1",
  "Substance3","Substance3","Substance3",
  "Substance1","Substance1","Substance1",
  "Substance4","Substance4","Substance4",
  "Substance1","Substance1","Substance1"))
        dataExample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, made new sample data to have more than 2 levels and twice repeated `Substance2`.

```
dataExample<-data.frame(Time=seq(1:10),
                        Data1=runif(10,5.3,7.5),
                        Data2=runif(10,4.3,6.5),
                        Application=c("Substance1","Substance1","Substance2",
                                      "Substance2","Substance1","Substance1","Substance2",
                                      "Substance2","Substance3","Substance3"))
```

Didn't make this as function to show each step.

Add new column `groups` to original data frame - this contains identifier for grouping of `Applications` - if substance changes then new group is formed.

```
dataExample$groups<-c(cumsum(c(1,tail(dataExample$Application,n=-1)!=head(dataExample$Application,n=-1))))
```

Convert to long format data for lines of data.

```
longDF<-melt(dataExample,id.vars=c("Time","Application","groups"))
```

Calculate positions for Substance identifiers. Used function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. For calculation only data that differs from first `Application` value are used (that's `subset()`). Then `Application` and `groups` are used for grouping of data. Calculated starting, middle and ending positions on x axis and y value taken as maximal `value` +0.3.

```
library(plyr)    
lineData<-ddply(subset(dataExample,Application != dataExample$Application[1]),
      .(Application,groups),
                summarise,minT=min(Time),maxT=max(Time),
                meanT=mean(Time),ypos=max(longDF$value)+0.3)
```

Now plot longDF data with `ggplot()` and `geom_line()` and add segments above plot with `geom_segment()` and text with `annotate()` using new data frame `lineData`.

```
ggplot(longDF,aes(Time,value,color=variable))+geom_line()+
  geom_segment(data=lineData,aes(x=minT,xend=maxT,y=ypos,yend=ypos),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  annotate("text",x=lineData$meanT,y=lineData$ypos+0.1,label=lineData$Application)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this code is exactly what I was looking for. But when I make it as a function R says, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object  'longDF' not found`. 

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See this [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes/10662937#10662937)