# Shiny and ggplot - trouble making the group= reactive

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

First post and first time using Shiny and ggplot2, so please bear with me. I'm having trouble getting ggplot to interpret an input$variable as a value for a group= option. I've found some guidance in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes?rq=1), but can't quite get it to work. I've pasted a simplified version of my code below, which produces an "input not found" error. Any ideas how to resolve?

**ui.r**

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Shiny: First App",
        tabPanel("Annual Trends",
                 verticalLayout(
                      titlePanel("Annual Subscriptions Data"),

                      selectInput("dim",
                          label = "Dimension of Interest",
                          choices = c("location", "package",
                                      "section", "price.level", "no.seats"),
                          selected = "location"),

                       plotOutput("plot"),
                      )
               )
    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

subscriptions = read.csv("data/subscriptions.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$plot <- renderPlot({
       ggplot(subscriptions, aes(x = season)) +
       geom_freqpoly(aes(x = season, group=input$dim, colour=input$dim))
  })  
})
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra comma after `plotOutput("plot")`. If it still doesn't work after removing the extra comma, you should post some sample data so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`, so that it will correctly evaluate `input$dim`:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(subscriptions, aes(x = season)) +
   geom_freqpoly(aes_string(x = "season", group=input$dim, colour=input$dim))
})
```