# Loop with grid.arrange instead of mfrow

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, ggplot2

I have this working loop with the basic plot function

```
#my_data is a data.frame defined before
day = c("2016-12-24","2016-12-25", "2016-12-31")
par(mfrow  =  c(length(day),1))
for (i in 8:length(my_data)){
    for (j in 1:length(day)){
        plot(x=my_data$Zeit[which(my_data$Datum == day[j])], y=my_data[which(my_data$Datum == day[j]),i], type="l", 
         main=colnames(my_data[i]), xlab=day[j], ylab=my_units[1,i])
    }
}
```

But instead of the basic plot function, I want to use ggplot. With the search function on this board I found de command "grid.arrange", but it somehow does not work.

Edit: This is my new code with "do.call". Thank you already for this hint.

Edit2: Now it works. I don't understand why, but with the "#Added" lines it does not print out the same plot three times.

```
for (i in 8:length(my_data)){
for (j in 1:length(day)){
  local({ #Added
    i <- i #Added
    t <- which(my_data$Datum == day[j])
    p[[j]] <<- ggplot(my_data[t,], aes(my_data$Zeit[t], my_data[t,i]))+  #Changed to <<-
    geom_line()+
    labs(x = "", y = my_units[[i]], title = colnames(my_units[i]))+
    theme_own()
  }) #Added
}
```

Edit: What I want to do is plot the data for several days (in this example three) in the same "picture". I want to repeat this for all columns (8:length(my_data)).

With this new code and "do.call" I do get three plots like I want, but these plots are all for the same (the last) day. Why are the first two dates overwritten?

Edit2: I found the hint here: [for loop with ggplots produces graphs with identical values but different headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627085/for-loop-with-ggplots-produces-graphs-with-identical-values-but-different-headin)

Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess exactly what your goal is because your example has a call to `grid.arrange` within a for-loop. But try `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plist, ncol=2))` in its place.

Comment: You need do.call any more , you can use `grid.arrange(grobs=plist)`

Comment: *dont need*  *^^