# ggplot2 + loop results in "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Tags: loops, ggplot2

I've been fumbling with this for a while now but let me start with the beginning.

This is how the first few lines of my data look like:

```
Year Action_mean_global Adventure_mean_global Fighting_mean_global Misc_mean_global Platform_mean_global
1 1980          0.3400000                   NaN                 0.77           0.6775                  NaN
2 1981          0.5936000                   NaN                  NaN              NaN               2.3100
3 1982          0.3622222                   NaN                  NaN           0.8700               1.0060
4 1983          0.4085714                   0.4                  NaN           2.1400               1.3860
5 1984          1.8500000                   NaN                  NaN           1.4500               0.6900
6 1985          1.7600000                   NaN                 1.05              NaN              10.7925
  Puzzle_mean_global Racing_mean_global Roleplaying_mean_global Shooter_mean_global Simulation_mean_global
1                NaN                NaN                     NaN             3.53500                    NaN
2           1.120000           0.480000                     NaN             1.00400                   0.45
3           3.343333           0.785000                     NaN             0.75800                    NaN
4           0.780000                NaN                     NaN             0.48000                    NaN
5           1.046667           1.983333                     NaN            10.36667                    NaN
6           0.802500                NaN                     NaN             1.00000                   0.03
  Sports_mean_global Strategy_mean_global Total_mean_global
1             0.4900                  NaN         1.2644444
2             0.1975                  NaN         0.7776087
3             0.5250                  NaN         0.8016667
4             3.2000                  NaN         0.9876471
5             3.0900                  NaN         3.5971429
6             1.9600                  NaN         3.8528571
```

They are all numeric.

Now, I simply wanted to do a plot with `ggplot() + geom_line()` to visualize change over year per genre. It works when doing it step by step, i.e.:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[1]))
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[2]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[3]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[4]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[5]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[6]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[7]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[8]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[9]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[10]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[11]))+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[12]))
```

(plot_vector simply contains all column-names except for `Year`)

However, doing it in a for-loop:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[1]))

for (plotnumber in 2:length(plot_vector))
{
  p1 <- p1 + 
    geom_line(aes_string(x = 'Year', y = plot_vector[plotnumber]))

}
```

I get the error message. Anyone can muster an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding lines with a for loop to a `ggplot` object may have caused the reported error message but has a general problem caused by *lazy evaluation*. This has been asked frequently on SO, see, e.g., [“for” loop only adds the final ggplot layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26235825/3817004), or [ggplot loop adding curves fails, but works one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42218688/3817004).

However, `ggplot2` works best when data are supplied in long format. Here, `melt()`from the `data.table` package is used to reshape `df`:

```
library(data.table)
molten <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c("Year"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(molten, aes(x = Year, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

This creates the following chart:

[image]

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 1980:1985, Action_mean_global = c(0.34, 
0.5936, 0.3622222, 0.4085714, 1.85, 1.76), Adventure_mean_global = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN, 0.4, NaN, NaN), Fighting_mean_global = c(0.77, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.05), Misc_mean_global = c(0.6775, NaN, 0.87, 
2.14, 1.45, NaN), Platform_mean_global = c(NaN, 2.31, 1.006, 
1.386, 0.69, 10.7925), Puzzle_mean_global = c(NaN, 1.12, 3.343333, 
0.78, 1.046667, 0.8025), Racing_mean_global = c(NaN, 0.48, 0.785, 
NaN, 1.983333, NaN), Roleplaying_mean_global = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN), Shooter_mean_global = c(3.535, 1.004, 0.758, 
0.48, 10.36667, 1), Simulation_mean_global = c(NaN, 0.45, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, 0.03), Sports_mean_global = c(0.49, 0.1975, 0.525, 
3.2, 3.09, 1.96), Strategy_mean_global = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN), Total_mean_global = c(1.2644444, 0.7776087, 0.8016667, 
0.9876471, 3.5971429, 3.8528571)), .Names = c("Year", "Action_mean_global", 
"Adventure_mean_global", "Fighting_mean_global", "Misc_mean_global", 
"Platform_mean_global", "Puzzle_mean_global", "Racing_mean_global", 
"Roleplaying_mean_global", "Shooter_mean_global", "Simulation_mean_global", 
"Sports_mean_global", "Strategy_mean_global", "Total_mean_global"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```