# multiple outliers in ggplot -> alpha to outlier.color

Tags: r, alpha, boxplot

I want to set my outlier points in a boxplot to be semitransparent
In [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010403/jitter-if-multiple-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot) they used "jitter" (similar idea, different approach)

my code

```
ggplot() + 
geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sistema, y=values, linetype = Sistema), 
             data=estacado, outlier.size=1, outlier.shape=2) + 
coord_flip() + 
labs(x="Sistema", y=expression(paste("RMSD ",(ring(A))))) +
opts(legend.position="none")
```

my data

```
>head(estacado)
    values   ind Sistema
1 0.310214 r24_a     R24
2 0.428232 r24_a     R24
3 0.460971 r24_a     R24
4 0.482923 r24_a     R24
5 0.492656 r24_a     R24
6 0.515591 r24_a     R24
> tail(estacado)
          values   ind Sistema
4999995 1.723030 g24_e     G24
4999996 1.718444 g24_e     G24
4999997 1.720745 g24_e     G24
4999998 1.737137 g24_e     G24
4999999 1.733106 g24_e     G24
5000000 1.738487 g24_e     G24
```

[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19202810/Rplot01.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19202810/Rplot01.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19202810/Rplot01.png)

In the mentioned link, they modified the function `geom_boxplot`; I was hoping something more easy like `outlier.colour= alpha("black", 1/2)` but that gives the error:

```
Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  could not find function "alpha"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of `ggplot2` version 0.9.0, the `alpha` function was moved to the (then new) `scales` package. To use it, you need to include

```
library("scales")
```

in addition to

```
library("ggplot2")
```

in your script.